# What does the nil returned by puts signify?

Tags: ruby, irb

When I use the puts command, especially in IRB I get a nil returned as part of the statement execution.

I was curious to know what it means on a general note.

Please find below a sample:-

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :021 > puts 3/2
1
 => nil
```

Your inputs would be really handy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every method in Ruby returns a value. `puts` doesn't really have any sort of useful value to return, so it returns `nil`.

Comment: But, it correctly calculated 1..why did it not return 1 instead of nil?  Im having a similar problem...